# Blurry fonts in notebooks

Tags: front-end, notebooks, fonts

May be this question does not belong to here, but I do not know where to post it.

I am using Windows 10 Pro 64bit and MMA 11.0.1.

My monitor (32inch) has a native resolution of 3820 * 2160 pixels.

When I use an overall screen magnification of 100% the notebook font and the menu items are much too small.

> When I increase the screen magnification to 150% or even more the font
>   (independent which one) is extremely blurry.

!!! ALL OTHER WINDOWS AND FONTS IN OTHER APPS ARE SHARP.

Do you have a solution for that, when monitors have 4K?

> **UPDATE: Answer from a Wolfram Technology Engineer**
>
> Mathematica's front-end does not support 4K resolution monitors fully
>   and is known to have some issues when used in 4K resolution monitors.
>   Our developers are currently working on this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this is something I have partially encountered before (though I can't guarantee it will will work for everyone, or even anyone other than me), the first thing I did was to use [this](http://windows10_dpi_blurry_fix.xpexplorer.com/) tool to fix scaling issues on Win10 (this is an external program, download at your own risk).  There is also a possible option modification that may work for you:

- Open Option Inspector (ctrl shift O)
- Set to Global Preferences
- Go to Formatting Options > Font Options > FontProperties
- Set ScreenResolution to Automatic

Again, there is no guarantee but this is what I have used in the past.

Comment: This is genius ... it works for me too ... since 2 years I am suffering with the blurring problem.

Comment: The only small thing: The input filed in the Mathematica documentation center is not high enough, I entered here `Plot`: http://i.imgur.com/bIQ54hR.png

Comment: Yes, that is also an issue, but unfortunately I am not aware of any fixes for it yet.

Comment: I have concurred with others in marking this question as a duplicate.  If you agree that it is one what do you think of my *Merging* this question into that one, which means your answer will be (permanently) moved over there?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: This is probably a good idea, but please keep that lowriniak solved for me the problem.

Comment: @lowriniak : When I start MMA and use a magnification of 200% everything is fine and sharp. But how can I start each notebook with this magnification?

Comment: @mrz I cannot control the Accepted answer; ElOmmy would have to Accept this again and he does not seem to visit the site any longer.  I would be glad to put a +50 bounty on this answer to distinguish it if that is agreeable to all involved.

Comment: @mrz Did you try the recommendation in the other Q&A?: `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, Magnification -> 2]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: yes, great this works for all notebooks and it seems to work also after mma is restarted. If I did not overview anything this is perfect and what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Just a last remark, I believe that all Win users with high resolutions displays should be informed about what lowriniak proposed (as long as Wolfram Research has no better solution ... I asked them about that).

Comment: (apologies for the delayed response) I'd be happy to do the edits.  @mrz to have all notebooks be set to 200% magnification go to Option Inspector, select Global Preferences, go to Notebook options, Display Options, and change the value of Magnification to 2.  This means all notebooks will be at 200% by default (notice the popup at the bottom will not change, this is *relative* to the global value)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as i know, there is no better solution except get a bigger screen. I met with the same issue, my solution was a 24-inch screen with 1080p resolution.